# How to add domain in act_window odoo

Tags: python, odoo-13

```html
<act_window
            id="account.action_move_line_select_tax_audit"
            name="Journal Items for Tax Audit"
            context="{'search_default_account_id': [active_id]}"
            res_model="account.move.line"
            view_id="account.view_move_line_tax_audit_tree"
            domain="[('user', '=', 'Ignored value')]"/>
```

***Edit:***

```
class something(models.Model):
  _inherit = "account.move.line"
  def _get_user(self):
    for r in self:
      r.user=self.env.user
      
  def _search branch(self,operator,value):
    return [('branch_id',operator,self.env.user.branch_id.id)]
    
  user =fields.Many2one('res.users', compute=_get_user, search=_search_branch)
```

I added domain like this.But not work.Can't add domain in act_window tag?.I change another domain like simple thing but not wrong.I think I am not wrong with my domain field.

Comment: It should work, make sure it is loaded.

Comment: @Kenly I still see the account move line with not same with current branch_id.

Comment: So your question is: How to make the domain work? It depends on the user implementation.

Comment: No.My domain is not work.I want to know is my usage is correct or not.Something wrong?@Kenly

Comment: I edited my code .Something wrong?@Kenly

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `_get_user` method, it is defined for `user` field but it try to set the `user_id` field value.

You need to rename `user_id` to `user`:

```
def _get_user(self):
    for r in self:
        r.user = self.env.user
```

Comment: Sorry I typed wrong spelling.Actually I use just r.user.Not user_id

Comment: After I changed the field name, The filter worked and I can see only the journal items that are linked to my branch.

Comment: Can you go Tax Report under account reporting and go to  Journal Items for Tax Audit.I see all journal item.You can see only filter journal item?

Comment: When I change user field to another name that really doesn't exit in domain, got no error and nothing change like domain="[('dfdfdfeeghe', '=', 'Ignored value')] .But I change name value to another name value.It work. What's wrong with me?@Kenly

Comment: You can't set any value, the left value should be a field name, you can read that at [Search domains](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/orm.html#search-domains).

Comment: No.I know the left value must be field value.But I use random value to test for that domain work or not.Actually If I don't use field name,I must be get error, but I didn't get error and use correct field doesn't also work.@Kenly

Comment: I tested it and it works, try to define a new branch for the current user and see what happens.

Comment: your odoo is enterprise version?

Comment: No, I made a test on Odoo CE.

Comment: @Kenly.I think something wrong in enterprise version.Can you able to test on enterprise?All I asked about all of my problem is in enterprise accounting.If you don't have enterprise version, no problem.Thanks

Comment: Whatever Thank you for your support. I have another question .If you have time, pls check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63795342/how-to-write-raw-sql-query-in-odoo.If you are busy, no problem.@Kenly

Answer (score 0):

```
 <act_window
       id="act_view_currency_rates"
       name="Currency Rates"
       view_mode='tree,form'
       view_id='view_currency_rate_tree'
       domain="[('currency_id','=', active_id)]"
       context="{'default_currency_id': active_id}"
       res_model="res.currency.rate"/>
```

context  for default search and return list
domain for filter records