# How to write raw sql query in odoo

Tags: python, odoo-13

I want to write raw sql query for following code.

```
product_ids = self.env['product.product'].with_context(warehouse=warehouse_id.ids).search([]).filtered(lambda p:p.qty_available > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The product [qty_available](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/stock/models/product.py#L26) is a computed field and the compute method [_compute_quantities](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/stock/models/product.py#L100) depends on the result of  [_compute_quantities_dict](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/stock/models/product.py#L121) to get the quantities dict and [_get_domain_locations](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/stock/models/product.py#L226) to parses the context and returns a list of `location_ids` based on it.

You need to write a query that gets the same result.

You can check the PostgreSQL log to see how many queries as executed for this python statement.

The following query is the last one executed to get the result (generated using a demo database):

```
SELECT min("stock_move".id) AS id, count("stock_move".id) AS "product_id_count" , sum("stock_move"."product_qty") AS "product_qty","stock_move"."product_id" as "product_id" 
                FROM "stock_location" as "stock_move__location_dest_id","stock_location" as "stock_move__location_id","stock_move"
                WHERE ("stock_move"."location_dest_id"="stock_move__location_dest_id"."id" AND "stock_move"."location_id"="stock_move__location_id"."id") AND (((("stock_move"."state" in ('waiting','confirmed','assigned','partially_available'))  AND  ("stock_move"."product_id" in (62,41,40,15,64,65,51,16,17,18,19,20,21,23,24,55,58,60,54,56,57,61,53,52,12,13,14,25,30,26,48,39,36,49,31,34,45,42,5,8,29,43,33,38,46,32,6,27,35,28,44,37,7,50,66,59,67)))  AND  ("stock_move__location_dest_id"."parent_path"::text like '1/7/%'))  AND  (NOT (("stock_move__location_id"."parent_path"::text like '1/7/%')))) AND ("stock_move"."location_dest_id"="stock_move__location_dest_id"."id") AND (("stock_move"."company_id" in (1))  OR  "stock_move__location_dest_id"."company_id" IS NULL )
                GROUP BY "stock_move"."product_id"
                ORDER BY "id"
```

You need to carefully study the `_compute_quantities` method code to know how Odoo calculates these values.

***Edit:***
Concider the following statement:

```
self.env['stock.warehouse'].search([('branch_id', '=', self.env.user.branch_id.id)], 
                                   order="id desc")
```

To turn the above statement to an SQL query you need to know what [search](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/odoo/models.py#L4423) method does

For example, Odoo will call [_where_calc](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/odoo/models.py#L4406) to computes the `WHERE` clause needed to implement the domain and automatically add the `('active', '=', 1)` to the domain.

#### Example:

***query_str***

```
SELECT "stock_warehouse".id FROM "stock_warehouse" WHERE (("stock_warehouse"."active" = %s)  AND  ("stock_warehouse"."branch_id" = %s)) AND ("stock_warehouse"."company_id" in (%s)) ORDER BY "stock_warehouse"."id" DESC
```

***args***

```
[True, 1, 1]
```

***The final query:***

```
SELECT "stock_warehouse".id FROM "stock_warehouse" WHERE (("stock_warehouse"."active" = true)  AND  ("stock_warehouse"."branch_id" = 1)) AND ("stock_warehouse"."company_id" in (1)) ORDER BY "stock_warehouse"."id" DESC
```

Comment: I really feel complicated. Can I know how to change my code to query?@Kenly

Comment: You need to check ``_compute_quantities`` line by line. check my edit for a simple call to search method.